# Unexpected JavaScript Actions reported by my Users

Tags: javascript, browser

My users keep complaining that a link does not show up for them. For me, I have tested this on several browsers and it works for me.

What **should** happen is that a process is started via AJAX using JQuery and once that is done I keep checking with the server via AJAX how much of the process has been done and once the process is complete I show them a link. But a lot of users tell me that it shows them the link and it **quickly disappears back to showing 100.0%**!

I can't see how I can fix this and I was hoping you guys could help me write something fool proof so that the link is always shown!

Here is the code concerned (its been shortened).

```
var startTime;
var continueTime;
var done = false;
function convertNow(validURL){
       startTime = setTimeout('getStatus();', 6000); 
       $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "main.php",
       data: 'url=' + validURL + '&filename=' + fileNameTxt,
       success: function(msg){
      done = true;     
      $("#loading").hide("slow");
      $("#done").html("LINK SHOWN HERE");   
       }//function

     });//ajax

}//function convertNow
function getStatus()
{       
        if(done==false){            
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "fileReader.php",
        data: 'textFile=' + fileNameTxt,
        success: function(respomse){
        textFileResponse = respomse.split(" ");
        $("#done").html("PROGRESS SHOWN HERE IN PERCENTAGES");
        }
        });//ajax
        continueTime = setTimeout('getStatus();', 3000); 
        }
}
```

Thanks all

P.S. I have this question before and was given an idea of using a conditional in the function but that didn't work when it should have!!

### UPDATE

I have some of my users what OS and browsers they are using and they usually say a Mac Os and firefox or safari. Not sure if that help with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour described by the users suggests that the `success` callback of your `getStatus` function is called after the one in `convertNow`. You should test `done` variable in this callback

```
function getStatus(){
    if(done==false){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "fileReader.php",
            data: 'textFile=' + fileNameTxt,
            success: function(respomse){
                // FIX : Already done, just ignore this callback
                if (done) return;

                textFileResponse = respomse.split(" ");
                $("#done").html("PROGRESS SHOWN HERE IN PERCENTAGES");

                // BONUS : call getStatus only when previous ajax call is finished
                continueTime = setTimeout('getStatus();', 3000);
            }
        });//ajax
    }
}
```

EDIT : This solution should prevent the bug from appearing most of the time, but there is still a chance. The only way to be sure is to remove the callback from `convertNow` and let the one in `getStatus` set the link when the processing is done (don't forget to allow only one call to `getStatus` at a time, see "BONUS" modification above).

Comment: Sweeet! I understand your logic. I have added both implementations to my JS code and it works for me great. I am sure my users will stop complaining now! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If `done` is never set back to `false` then the reported behavior would be expected upon the second call to `convertNow`.

Since the ajax call in `convertNow` uses GET instead of POST, it is possible that a browser is returning a cached result whenever parameters are identical to a previous call.